# Disable menu button?

Tags: android, menu

I have a custom menu options that I want to disable it from popping up if a button on screen is clicked..

I thought of using this code but it doesnt work:

```
@Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
     if (Schedule)
         menu.getItem(1).setVisible(View.GONE);
     return true;
 }
```

Is there a way to prevent the menu button from doing anything?  Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the documentation:

```
You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown.
```

So I'm guessing this will work:

```
@Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
     .... Code .....
     return !Schedule;
 }
```

That is assuming that you want the menu to display when `Schedule` is equal to false.

Comment: In other words, just return `false` to disable the menu. Worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, but I was addressing his question specifically at the time.  Usually there's a condition to disable it anyway as you would simply not create one to begin with if you want it always disabled.

Comment: This didn't immediately work for me, but this solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9546316/602245