# How I hide the menu button for one activity

Tags: android, menu, hide

There is an activity which has no menu item. So I want to hide the menu button. Is there any way to achieve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 15):

I figured out how this can be done. In your AndroidManifest.xml, you need to specify something like the following:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
          android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Basically, `minSdkVersion` is the minimum Android SDK version that you application supports (in my case, 2.2) and `targetSdkVersion` is the version you're "targetting" (i.e. your "preferred" version - in my case, that's 4.0)

By default, `targetSdkVersion` is the same as `minSdkVersion`, and if you leave that pre-Honeycomb, you're basically telling Android that your app is "legacy" and it'll always show the menu button.

If you make `targetSdkVersion` post-Honeycomb, then the menu button will only be shown if you actually have menu items defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using the onPrepareOptionsMenu, where you set the menu item that you want to show to user,[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29][1]

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29. Do not inflate using the xml just do it manually.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to hide the system standard options menu because it contains no menu item. I think onPrepareOptionsMenu just modifies the menu item of the system standard options menu.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to include in your code so that the menu items are not automatically visible when you start the activity.

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

//add the menu items here

return true;

}
```

By writing like this the menu items are visible only when you click on the menu button of the android smartphone

Comment: Sorry I haven't clearly state my question. I want to hide the options menu totally when user enters my activity.I have override onCreateOptionsMenu method and return false, but the options menu still can be seen.

Comment: return true then you can see the menu only when the menu button on the phone is pressed. This wont start as soon as the activity starts. It pop ups when the user presses the menu button on the phone

Answer (score 0):

> So I want to hide the menu button

On the vast majority of Android devices, the "menu button" is a physical thing, and cannot be hidden, any more than I can hide a mountain or a molehill.

On Honeycomb, if you do not define an options menu, you should not get the "overflow" button in the upper right corner, in the action bar.

If you are trying this on some non-compliant Android device that does its own soft menu button, you are out of luck.